Is a random circle rotation weak mixing almost surely?
Consider the random circle rotation $x \to x + Z \text{ mod 1}$ on $([0, 1], \text{Lebesgue})$ where at each rotation, $Z$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$ and independent of previous rotations.
Is it true that almost surely, the system is weak mixing?
Remark: Note that the rotation by a fixed number is never weak mixing due to being an isometric system.

What do you mean by "almost surely" on  $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$?

I mean almost surely with respect to the probability space underlying the independent random variables $Z_i$. @AlessandroDellaCorte

Note that this is a different $[0, 1]$ than the underlying space of the dynamics.

If you take $[0, 1]^{\mathbb N}$ as a model for the probability space, then the natural measure is the countable product of the uniform measure, and almost surely means with respect to this.

I would have asked what you meant by weak-mixing. It's normally defined for a fixed transformation, when it is equivalent to the non-existence of non-constant eigenfunctions. Did you mean the condition that Will Sawin showed does not hold in his answer? (this seems the most reasonable guess). Maybe it would make more sense to define the random rotation as a skew product $T\colon [0,1)^\mathbb Z\times [0,1)\to [0,1)^\mathbb Z\times [0,1)$ that is $T(\omega,t)=(\sigma(\omega),t+\omega_0\bmod1)$.

So for every choice of $\omega$, you get a fixed sequence of transformation and we ask if this is weak mixing almost surely wrt $\omega$. Will Sawin's answer shows in fact it's almost surely not weak mixing! @AnthonyQuas

I guess I’m wondering whether the notion of “weak mixing for a random composition of maps” has been defined elsewhere, and whether it has proved to be useful.

I am not too familiar with the formal theory of random dynamical systems, but asking for ergodic/mixing properties of the random system feels rather natural no? @AnthonyQuas

I would say the definitions are good definitions if they lead to interesting behaviour. For a regular system, ergodicity is interesting, because, for example, the conclusion of Birkhoff's theorem is particularly nice. The regular definition of weak-mixing is nice because it relates to eigenvalues, and can be leveraged to prove theorems such as Furstenberg/Szemerédi's theorem about arithmetic progressions in dense subsets of the integers. It may be that the random versions are similarly consequential. Or it may not...

@Anthony Quas Only one way to find out

I think at least ergodicity of random transformations is interesting in the context of “card shuffling”, or in general trying to uniformly mix a space with random operations…

In any case, if random dynamical systems are of interest at all, I can’t imagine that their ergodic properties would not be of interest.

No,
$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}| \mu (A) \cap T^{-k}(B) - \mu(A)\mu(B)|$$ is a sum of i.i.d random varables, since $T^{-k}$ are i.i.d uniform circle rotations so by the law of large numbers it converges almost surely to the expectation of one of these variables, which is  $$ \mathbb E | \mu (A) \cap F^{-1}(B) - \mu(A)\mu(B)|$$ for $F$ a random rotation.
This is nonzero for $A,B$ any two intervals. In fact, it is equal to the long run average in the case that $T$ is an irrational rotation, so this reduces to the case you already know.

Just noting for myself - the key here is a composition of iid random circle rotations is independent of its earlier iterates, just due to the niceness of uniformly chosen rotations. Very cool.

@NateRiver Yes, although independence is not so strictly necessary since the law of large numbers is robust to many forms of dependence between the random variables and we only need a very weak form of the law of large numbers.
